# Glue crawler only doing top level of DynamoDb Export

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena, glue-crawler

I'm trying to query a dynamodb export using AWS Glue and Athena.  I set up a glue crawler to create tables from the exported file, but the output table of interest "data" has only one column "item".  Item is a struct which has an assortment of nested files such that the table definition looks like this:

```
root
|-- Item: struct
|    |-- pk: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- sk: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- createdAt: struct
|    |    |-- N: string
|    |-- event: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- data: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- resultId: struct
|    |    |-- NULL: boolean
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- updatedAt: struct
|    |    |-- N: string
|    |-- answers: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- result: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
|    |-- interactions: struct
|    |    |-- S: string
```

What do I need to do to be able to use Athena to query the table so that I get back a response with columns: pk, sk, createdAt etc. rather than just a row with everything packed into one struct?

I've tried applying a transform in a Glue ETL script,using function that looks like:

```
def transform(rec):
    rec["pk"] = rec["Item"]["pk"]["S"]
    del rec["Item"]["pk"]
    ...
```

This appears to work for the first few keys (which I think are in every row, but when I hit columns that are not in every row, it begins to fail...

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to use a JSON classifier.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json

The classifier should look something similar to this: `$[*]`

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this, but there's basicially been no change.  Have tried the following:
>$[*]
>$.item[*]
>$.item[*].item

no real apparent change, but still not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Glue has a bug, or at least it used to. Create a new crawler with the classifier and try it.

Comment: Still not working? Is this something I need to use a glue ETL for?  It seems like it should be so simple.  All I want is data['item']

Comment: So you created a new crawler and used the classifier I shared and create a new table in your glue catalog and it didn't work?

Comment: Correct.  And tried a bunch of alternatives like $.item[*], still no dice

Comment: Something doesn't add up. I would suggest manually creating the table definition if you need a quick solution.

Comment: I figured it out, my issues was that this was being ported from a no-sql database and so I had to use a glue ETL script and DynamicFrame.relationalize() to put things into a suitable format.